# Getting error 'You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.` after trying many solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I'm having a problem that I've seen others have and have tried many solutions offered but nothing works. When trying to deploy a rails app to Heroku and get to the point where I have to `heroku rake db:migrate`, I get the error `You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.`

I was initially running Ruby 2.6.0 but upgraded to 2.6.1 after reading some posts that this had been fixed. Running Rails 5.2.2.

I have tried to:

- delete lockfile and bundle install
- gem update bundler (to 2.0)
- bundle install --system
- heroku buildpacks:set
- gem install bundler -
- tried deleting my Rails app on Heroku and reset the Heroku repo and started over
- tried `heroku rake:detach rake db:migrate` or something like that. This allowed for the migration but then I got errors and the dyno crashed.
- tried creating a Procfile.dev with the commands `web: bundle exec bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
  worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

Here are some bits of code that could perhaps shed some light on my situation.

my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'httparty'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'jwt-auth', '~> 3.0'
# gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
gem "figaro"


gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'rename'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'


end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

my logfile when I attempt to `heroku open`:

```
2019-05-20T19:18:37.154031+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:18:37.154031+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:18:36.926353+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:18:36.926353+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:52.512189+00:00 app[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:52.512189+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.944345+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3ab64d18 by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.944345+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.957391+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to console@0:Free rake@0:Free web@1:Free by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.639739+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-defined-55908) by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.656114+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-defined-55908 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.639739+00:00 app[api]: Running release v4 commands by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:53.656114+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:19:57.332749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 46673 -e production`
2019-05-20T19:19:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-05-20T19:19:59.100443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-20T19:19:59.107493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038377+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038393+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038394+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `new'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038395+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `initialize'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038397+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:234:in `new'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038398+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:234:in `to_definition'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038399+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038402+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:34:in `build'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038404+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038405+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038406+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038408+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038409+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038410+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038411+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.038413+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2019-05-20T19:19:59.079452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-20T19:20:02.333495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 48713 -e production`
2019-05-20T19:20:05.071247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-20T19:20:05.054251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972527+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972545+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972547+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `new'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972548+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:83:in `initialize'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972550+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:234:in `new'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972555+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:234:in `to_definition'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972557+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972559+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:34:in `build'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972560+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972562+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972563+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972565+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972566+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972568+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972570+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
2019-05-20T19:20:04.972571+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2019-05-20T19:20:10.571751+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:20:13.762466+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: State changed from starting to up
2019-05-20T19:20:13.765155+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: Awaiting client
2019-05-20T19:20:13.799505+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2019-05-20T19:20:18.499328+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: State changed from up to complete
2019-05-20T19:20:18.474268+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: Process exited with status 20
2019-05-20T19:22:57.021525+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:23:00.672287+00:00 heroku[run.2331]: State changed from starting to up
2019-05-20T19:23:00.689268+00:00 heroku[run.2331]: Awaiting client
2019-05-20T19:23:00.740482+00:00 heroku[run.2331]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2019-05-20T19:23:05.400934+00:00 heroku[run.2331]: State changed from up to complete
2019-05-20T19:23:05.385380+00:00 heroku[run.2331]: Process exited with status 20
2019-05-20T19:24:17.980956+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user demiansims@gmail.com
2019-05-20T19:24:20.590557+00:00 heroku[run.2935]: Awaiting client
2019-05-20T19:24:20.812085+00:00 heroku[run.2935]: State changed from starting to up
2019-05-20T19:24:20.609194+00:00 heroku[run.2935]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2019-05-20T19:24:25.018756+00:00 heroku[run.2935]: State changed from up to complete
2019-05-20T19:24:24.994002+00:00 heroku[run.2935]: Process exited with status 20
2019-05-20T19:32:18.494661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=faunagram-api.herokuapp.com request_id=53b89a56-41ac-46b6-b8e7-328c912db131 fwd="184.152.71.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-20T19:32:19.118662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=faunagram-api.herokuapp.com request_id=ca60c3fa-0092-48d1-807d-30f1f77b9745 fwd="184.152.71.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Hopefully this enough information. This has been kind of a nightmare.

Comment: How looks your `Gemfile.lock` (`BUNDLED WITH`)?

Comment: my `Gemfile.lock` always contains ` bundler (>= 1.3.0)` but at the bottom it says `bundled with 2.0.1`

Comment: Did you try simply `bundle exec heroku rails db:migrate`?

Comment: Just tried that. Still getting ```You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem that your installed bundler version is 2 or greater and Gemfile.lock is `BUNDLED WITH` 2 or greater,

I've ran into this many time, downgrading your bundler to 1.17.1 will do the trick for you :-

1. get your all bundler versions by running `gem list | grep "bundle"`
2. start removing them all by typing `gem uninstall bundler -v <version_here>`
3. Now you have no bundler gems installed, install the desired one by running `gem install bundler -v 1.17.1`
4. Delete `Gemfile.lock` file from your project
5. Navigate to your project directory and run `bundle install`
6. Check that your `Gemfile.lock` is `BUNDLED WITH` 1.17.1, usually your found this line at the end of file
7. you are ready to go, deploy your application and it will run

Hope this works with you.

Comment: Ok so this brings up another problem. When I try to start deleting all the versions of bundler which are clearly listed after running `gem list | grep "bundle"`, it tells bundler is not installed.

Comment: I would love some help on this. It won't let me uninstall the other versions. Only 2.0.1. I'm going in circles here and it's taken me a week to get a Rails app up to Heroku. Should it really be this hard?? When I try to uninstall the other versions of bundler that are listed there, it's says bundler not installed!!

Comment: the problem is that rails freezes specific bundler versions, you can solve this by running:- 
`gem install bundler -v 1.17.1` then `bundle _1.17.1_ install` and don't forget to delete `Gemfile.lock` before you run the second command,
and no I believe this is heroku issue not yours

Comment: Thanks for your help but sitll getting the same error. I tried what you suggested. Another thing that keeps happening is that I have to keep `rvm use --default 2.6.1` for Ruby. It keeps slipping back to `2.6.0`. Maybe that's another issue. Isn't there an issue with the system Ruby vs a local install? Again, maybe another issue. Also wondering if there are alternatives to Heroku for React/Rails.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to reinstall anything having to do with Ruby/Rails and if this would help? I'm using Ruby 2.6.1 and Bundler 2.0 which is what Heroku is asking for and yet an earlier version of Bundler is showing up in my Gemlock file and still installed on my machine which won't let me uninstall.

Comment: This worked for me!! It took nearly half a day to find the answer, thank you!!

Comment: Even though this works, I'm curious, how come we can't have the installed bundler version as 2 or greater and the Gemfile.lock Bundled with 2 or greater?

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion (not a solution) but I don't have to karma to comment, so forgive me.  Three things to try:

`bundle install && bundle update`

`bundle exec [COMMAND]`, i.e. `bundle exec heroku rake db:migrate`

Also, go through your `gemfile` and run
`gem pristine [GEMNAME]` on each one.

I've been there.  Good luck and please update if you do solve it!